# Push to GitHub from public PC after passwords deprecation

Tags: git, authentication, github, credentials

I need to push to GitHub from console from a public computer, but GitHub will no longer accept account passwords:
https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

I could not install ssh on a public computer and I don't see any other option except save GitHub token somewhere in a public place.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, Git is installed in conjunction with OpenSSH.  Git for Windows includes OpenSSH, and OpenSSH is also included in Windows 10.  Most Unix systems that have Git installed will have OpenSSH installed automatically.

Assuming that one of those is the case, you can then use an SSH key on a flash drive and set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/flash/drive/id_ed25519"` when performing those operations.

If you really don't have OpenSSH already installed, you could use a password manager on your phone and then type in the token by hand, possibly using the `cache` credential helper.  You could also try to boot the system from a live USB drive and then use Git from there with a suitable SSH key also stored on the drive.

Comment: I believe it's insecure to store your private SSH key on flash and moreover insert it on a public computer. Type the token by hand is painful, and live USB is almost always quite long and impossible in general.

Comment: There's also the possibility of using a newer version of OpenSSH with the sk-* types of keys, which use a hardware security key.  But I would honestly say that if you are worried about the risk of an SSH key on a flash drive, then you are no better off using a password or token or doing any sensitive operations on a public computer, which are equally insecure, and you need to adopt a totally different approach.  That's not to say your concerns aren't legitimate, just that there are no good options within your threat model.